# Should I always check if client successfully received data sent from server? (Socket programming)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

I'm trying to implement file server that sends requested file to the client.
I implemented sending, and receiving part of Server and client, using TCP protocol.

My server sends data packet dequeued from the Packet queue until packet queue is empty, and my Client Receives until received packet number is same as desired packet number.

I used SendAsync() and ReceiveAsync() method from .Net framework.

My program Seems to have no problem when I debug it, But in the real run, 
Client Seems to miss some packets sent from the server.. Even Server sent data packets, for some reason, client couldn't receive some data packets. I have no clue how this can happen.

Shouldn't TCP protocol ensure Receiving every packets sent from the server?
Do you have any clues why this happens?

Here is my code.. 
Receive_completed is callback method for ReceiveAsync() which is called after 
ReceuveAsync is completed
and Process_receive function always reads every received bytes from ReceiveAsync(), and returns true if it has completed reading packet (Otherwise, return false, and Receive() method will be called again)

and.. ignore OperationCompleted, and _receivedProperly..

```
internal void Receive()//method for receiving the call
    {
        if (_operationState)
        {
            try
            {
                bool pending =_user.ClientSocket.ReceiveAsync(_receiveArg); // This will spawn a new thread and call Receive_completed as callback method
                if (pending == false)
                {
                    _receivePendingThread = new Thread(CallReceiveCompleted); //Start New thread
                    _receivePendingThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ExceptionHandler(exception, CommunicatorError.ObjectDisposed);
            }
        }
    }


    private void Receive_completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Receive)
        {
            bool transferCompleted = false;
            try
            {
                if (e.BytesTransferred == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Socket Closed");
                }
                if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Socket Error Occured");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ExceptionHandler(exception, CommunicatorError.SocketError);
                return;
            } //Checks for received bytes

            //call process_receive here
            transferCompleted = Process_receive(); //returns if more packets are left or not (This method Gurantees reading all received bytes from ReceiveAsync()


            if (_receivedProperly&& _operationState) //Succeded process
            {           
                if (transferCompleted && _operationState) Receive();//Receive if more bytes are left
                else if (_operationState)
                {// No more packets to be accepted additionally
                    CallReceiveCompleted();// Start Callback method
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: TCP *uses* packets in its implementation but the abstraction it exposes to higher layers is an *endless stream of bytes* in both directions. It offers *no* guarantee that calls of `Send` at one end will be matched 1-1 with calls of `Receive` at the other end. In particular, `Receive` *may* return as soon as it has a single byte available. That means you always need to check the *return value* from `Receive`, and if you want *messaging* (1-1 correspondence between "sends" at one end and "receives" at the other), it's up to *you* to implement that atop TCP.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But, shouldn't TCP protocol guarantee that every byte sent from Server is received, even it doesn't ensure 1-1? I've already checked amount of bytes that ReceiveAsync() has read..

Comment: Yes, TCP guarentees that the data arrives if the host is available. The host, however, might never read the data or read it after a longer delay or read it in different chunks than what you sent.

You have to create a protocol that ensures a useful exchange on top of TCP (or use an existing one - which should almost always be preferred)

Comment: Yes, it does. My first comment was based on the *ever so common* mistake people make believing that they get 1-1 (and the fact that your question refers to *packets*, despite those being *hidden* by the TCP abstraction reinforced that feeling). It's likely, though, that it's still *related* to buffers being mishandled on the receive side. If you want more assistance, we'd need to see some code, preferably a [mcve]

Comment: I updated my code (Please yield it's not very clean..) I thought I read every bytes received by ReceiveAsync() by calling Process_receive().

Comment: Since you pass neither the `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, nor just the `BytesTransferred` to any further functions, how can you think you're properly dealing with it. *That* is what tells you how many bytes of (whatever buffer you've provided) have actually been populated.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that SocketAsyncEventArgs is passed to Process_receive() by global variable.. Sorry for that.. But I found another error inside 'Process_receive()'. I had problem handling with buffers as you said. Thank you for your comments. It was really helpful.